# Remove duplicates from array list using basically just brackets with a single integer value

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates

In short the only operation you can use directly on the array is the brackets ( ​[ integer_value ]​ ) with a single integer value. And I'm not allowed to move data to another data structure and back to the list in this problem.

remove_duplicates removes every duplicate in the array

This is my code so far:

```
class Array:
    def __init__(self):
        self.capacity = 4
        self.size = 0
        self.arr = [0] * self.capacity
    
    def insert(self, value, index):
        if index > self.size or index < 0:
            raise IndexOutOfBounds()
        if self.size >= self.capacity:
            self.resize()
        i = self.size
        while(i > index):
            self.arr[i] = self.arr[i - 1]
            i -= 1
        self.arr[index] = value
        self.size += 1
        if self.size > 1:
            self.is_ordered = False

    #adds to the back of the list
    def append(self, value):
        self.insert(value, self.size)
    
    def remove_duplicates(self):
        for i in range(0,self.size-1):
            if self.arr[i] == i:
                self.arr[i] = self.arr[i+1]
            self.size -= 1
    
    def __str__(self):
        str_val = ""
        for i in range(self.size-1):
            str_val += str(self.arr[i]) + ", "
        if self.size > 0:
            str_val += str(self.arr[self.size - 1])
        return str_val

    def resize(self):
        tmp_arr = [0] * self.capacity * 2
        for i in range(self.size):
            tmp_arr[i] = self.arr[i]
        self.arr = tmp_arr
        self.capacity *= 2

def test_array():
    array = Array()
    array.append(1)
    array.append(2)
    array.append(1)
    array.append(2)
    print(array)
    array.remove_duplicates()
    print(array)

test_array()
```

And my output:

```
1, 2, 1, 2
1
```

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: i should get 1, 2 in my output but i only get 1

Comment: In `self.arr[i] == i`, you compare a value to it's index, why so ?

Comment: it's not considered ideal, to modify the data structure that you are iterating over in place

Comment: Well now that i look at it self.arr[i] == i doesn't make sense, any suggestion on how i would implement it instead

Comment: is the goal just to remove duplicates in place

Comment: Check my suggested solution @mattyboo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not the most efficient way, but you could make a helper function that "removes" the item at the given index be shifting everything after it left 1 and decrementing `size`.

```
def remove_at(self, index):
    # Shift everything after index left 1
    for i in range(index, self.size-1):
        self.arr[i] = self.arr[i + 1]
    self.size -= 1
        
def remove_duplicates(self):
    i = 0
    # Can't use for i in range(self.size) since self.size changes in loop
    while i < self.size:
        # Check each index after i to see if it is a dupe
        j = i + 1
        while j < self.size:
            if self.arr[i] == self.arr[j]:
                self.remove_at(j)
            else:
                j += 1
        i += 1
```